# Replacing bathroom exhaust fan with light, using separate switches to operate fan and light

Tags: wiring, bathtub, fans

OK...my house 1996, 12/2 wiring throughout.
Replacement unit, same as old has same wiring, white, black, blue and ground.
Power source has black, white and ground only.
Obviously white all go together.
I tied the black and blue together in the unit and connected to incoming black lead.
The result, both switches operate fan and light together.
Furthermore I could swear the we 2 white leads in the old fan not capped and tied to nothing.
So how do I wire this????

Comment: HOW ABOUT PICTURES OF THE CEILING AND SWITCH BOX.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both the switch and the fan/light wiring boxes please?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to individual switch fan and light with 12/2 cable

For that you need a 3d wire, 12/3 cable.

Or go fancy and install a remote in the ceiling that will act as a switch.